# xcconfig has no effect when running 'swift package generate-xcodeproj'

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, xcconfig, xcode-project

I am creating an xcode proj with `swift package generate-xcodeproj`. The resulting project has a few targets, that correspond to the dependencies of the project. Some of them have `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` set to 8.0, some to 13.5, and the compilation fails, saying:

```
Compiling for iOS 8.0, but module 'SwiftProtobuf' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.5
```

If I go manually into the build settings of the generated xcodeproj and change `IPHONES_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` of all the targets to 13.5, then it builds.

So I tried to create a `build.xcconfig` and generating the xcodeproj with the following content and command:

**build.xcconfig:**

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET[sdk=iphoneos*] = 13.5
```

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj --xcconfig-overrides build.xcconfig
```

But this has no effect. If I `git add` the xcodeproj after I run `swift package generate-xcodeproj`, and then run `swift package generate-xcodeproj --xcconfig-overrides build.xcconfig`, I don't see any diff. Which suggests that it has absolutely no impact, right?

How should I use xcconfig to set the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET of all the targets of the generated xcodeproj?

Comment: Just stumbled across the same issue - did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: No, I gave up =/

Comment: Sad to hear.. I had the issue that one of my dependencies has a deployment target of iOS 14.4 but when I generate my Xcode project my target always stays at 14.0. therefore I hoped that the xconfig files could help